# Edit UI - Python Init function localization with QTranslator?

Tags: pyqgis

I have  interaction with layer defined by custom designed UIs. 
In layer properties the  following settings: Edit UI - customline.ui and Python Init function: customline_set.py.

```
#coding: utf8
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

nameField = None
myDialog = None

def formOpen(dialog,layerid,featureid):
    global myDialog
    myDialog = dialog
    global nameField

    translator = QTranslator()
    loc = QSettings().value('locale/userLocale')[0:2]
    print loc
    filename = "\\i18n\\customline_%s.qm" % loc
    print filename
    translator.load(filename)
    QCoreApplication.installTranslator(translator)

    print QCoreApplication.translate('editForm',"Generals")
    # return translated string ok
```

---

The code work without error but the UI it's not displayed in selected language.

Can anyone point me in the direction of the mistake here?

Answer (score 1):

i can't detect an error on sight but maybe this helps:

On some systems the user locale is not available and your **loc**-variable will be NULL, then your code will trow an error.

I use the the following code in my plugins:

```
    locale = QtCore.QSettings().value("locale/userLocale")
    if not locale: locale == 'en' 
    else: locale = locale[0:2]
    localePath = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'i18n', 
              'geopunt4qgis_{}.qm'.format(locale))
    if os.path.exists(localePath):
        self.translator = QtCore.QTranslator()
        self.translator.load(localePath)
        if QtCore.qVersion() > '4.3.3': 
           QtCore.QCoreApplication.installTranslator(self.translator)
```

Comment: it's ok, but not this is the problem. Tha translator loading it's ok and functional (print QCoreApplication.translate('editForm',"Generals") - it's working)

Answer (score 1):

A bit late, but it might help other people.
I had the same issue (python plugin for QGIS, `QCoreApplication.translate()` giving the correct result but no translation showing in QGIS itself).

In the end, I took example from the [Table Manager plugin](https://github.com/borysiasty/tablemanager). I created a `MyPlugin.pro` file which identifies all the files containing text that should be translated (in my case, `.ui` and `.py` files).

Then I used the command `pylupdate4 MyPlugin.pro`, which generates (or updates) your `.ts` files. `.ts` files can then be manually edited to add translations (it's XML-like format); it is also possible to edit them using [QT 4 Linguist](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/linguist-manual.html), which provides a GUI to properly handle QT 4 translations.

After that, don't forget to use `lrelease MyPlugin_locale.ts` to generate the corresponding `.qm` file which is actually used.

Note that I work on Ubuntu 12.04. The command `pylupdate4` may be different on other systems.

Relevant link that helped me :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18921213/translation-file-still-working-after-modifying-the-source