# Multi Language support for QGIS python plugin

Tags: qgis-plugins, qgis-2.8, internationalization

Is there any method for python plugin in QGIS 2.8 to support multiple languages.(including .ui files that is call from this python).Please anyone can help i am new to this environment

Answer (score 2):

From what I understand, you are trying to support internationalization in a plugin you are developping. It is possible, although not very well documented. Please have a look at this answer which contains relevant information and links : https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/176200/64955.

In short : the best way is to look at other plugins. You have to create a `.pro` file in a `i18n` directory, then use [QT 4 Linguist](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/linguist-manual.html) to provide your own translation (this will create a `.ts` file), or (alternatively) manually create a `.ts` file. Finally, run `lrelease` to generate a `.qm` (compiled) file.

If you edit your plugin (either `.py` or `.ui` files), you will have to run `pylupdate4` to update the `.ts` file, then `lrelease` to update the `.qm` file.

Additional link : [Internationalisation of PyQt4 Applications](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/i18n.html).